# Can we drop the condition of "converges to limit p"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**QUESTION**- I came across a question that sequence is converges to  $'\;p\;'$ if all of its proper subsequences converges to $'p'$

but my question is can we change the condition " converges to $p$ " to just only "converges"( for all the subsequences). Then is it still convergent or not?

I tried with different examples but in some of examples some of there subsequences are not even convergent

for eg.  $a_n=(-1)^n$  but its $a_{3n}$ subsequence is not convergent , i tried alot of sequences but get no result.

Please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The statement "a sequence converges if and only if all its subsequences converge" is true. A sequence is its own subsequence, so if all subsequences converge, then so does the sequence itself. And if a sequence converges, then according to your statement all its subsequences converge as well (to the same limit even).

Comment: its about all proper subsequences. according to your answer its true because in answer you are assuming subsequence  so sequence it self  subsequence. but here we want proper subsequences.

Comment: Then just take the subsequence which drops only the first element. Taking away a finite number of elements doesn't change the limit behavior.